# Securing files on web-server and accessing them via iPhone app

Tags: php, ios, xcode, security, ssl

I need to store thousands of PDFs on a web-server which need to be secured (encrypted or access permission based?).

I want the only way to access these files to be via an iPhone app which I'm currently making, which is username/password protected. (I usually use php to communicate from the app to the database/files)

1. Which technologies should I use to protect the files in the first place?
2. What iOS/php code/frameworks should I use to display them on the device?
3. Do I need to encrypt the transfer, over ssl or something?

Thanks in advance, Leigh

Comment: There are loads of possibilities here and which one you go for could depend upon the level of security you require. Having said that, I achieved something similar using `ASP.Net` for the document-server. It's built in restrictions have been adequate for my purposes so far.

As far as displaying them on the device, I used a `UIWebview` for this, as explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296260/how-to-upload-pdf-file-from-ibook-or-other-app-in-ipad-app/19297490#19297490

Comment: One way is; to store the PDF files outside the document root and serve the files with some secured PHP system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the PDF on your app, you can use [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html). See [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403). Something like:

```
NSURL *url = ... // the file URL for the PDF
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
controller.delegate = self;
[controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Clearly, you have to specify your view controller as conforming to the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` protocol, and, at the very least, implement the `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview`:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
    return self;
}
```

You can also view PDFs in a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but the document interaction controller is probably better.

To encrypt the transfer, you should employ SSL (e.g. use HTTPS instead  of HTTP). You obviously should also make sure that you never send/store the password in the clear.

In terms of protecting the files on the server, at the very least make sure that they're not accessible without going through some authorization process. That is, don't just put the files on the web server and then reply upon some application level security to retrieve the URLs. Store the files elsewhere outside the web server's root and control access to the files through your secure web interface. Always assume your URLs can be compromised. Depending upon the level of security required, you might also want to encrypt the files on the server and have the app decrypt them.

For general security concerns, I might suggest checking out WWDC 2012 video [The Security Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=704). Or WWDC 2011 videos [Security Overview](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=202) and [Securing Application Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=208). Also see the [Security Starting Point for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Security_iPhone/) document.

Comment: Thanks I'll watch those, for point 3 what would you suggest using, I know you can protect directories with htaccess but don't know if that would be good enough, or how to give access to the iPhones.

Comment: @lellis2k In terms of ensuring that the PDFs are not accessible directly, I like user488074's suggestion, namely make sure that the PDFs are not on the web server's web-accessible documents tree at all. Put the PDFs somewhere outside the web directory structure, which ensures that they're only accessible via your server's PHP (or whatever) code. Then make sure that that server PHP code does the necessary authentication.

Answer (score 2):

1. If those PDF files contains sensitive information you should encrypt them using an unbreakable encryption algorithm, such as AES-256, use mcrypt for symmetric encryption (see [php.net/mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt)).
2. I would recommend you to popup the default PDF reader of iOS, that would be the most easy way to do it.
3. Again, if those file are super sensitive or something - Of course, use SSL/TLS. It is recommended to use it anyway.

Comment: So with this method would I be encrypting the files locally with mcrypt, uploading them. Then decrypting them temporarily just before I send them over SSL?

Comment: No, you should encrypt & store them in the webserver, once a file is requested > you decrypt it On-The-Fly and send them over ssl.